# Optimizing the layer lines of a 3d printed part, based on subjected forces

Tags: stresses, forces, composite

I was directed here from the 3d printing stackexchange...

For years I have been fortunate to only have had to make 3D prints that don't require a large amount of force on them. But recently (since delving into VR accessories), I've had a lot of parts break between the layers of the printed parts. For this reason, I'd like to know the best angle to print an object, depending on the forces that will be subjected to it.

The way I see it, most of my prints could be simplified as follows:

[image: Graphic of a rectangular object with two holes labeled 'A' and 'B']

"A" is a hole for a bolt, "B" is also a hole for a bolt. They are separated by a distance 
. Bolt "A" receives a downward acting force 1
, whereas bolt B (by Newtonian physics) must receive an equal and opposite force that acts upwards (1=2
).

**Importantly,** this is **not** an overhead view. It is the view of a person watching the object being printed (side profile).

[image: Graphic of a rectangular object with force 1 in a downward vector on hole 'A' and force 2 in an upward vector on hole 'B' with both forces equal to each other]

The problem comes when you consider the torque acting on the object by the distance 
. You might think that you could just print the layers like this horizontally (solution 1):

[image: Previous graphic but with added 'layer line's perpendicular to forces 1 and 2]

But actually, because of the distance 
between the forces, there is a rotational (torque) force acting here. I can't really explain it in words, so consider how much stronger the print would be if you printed the object at a 45-degree angle like this:

[image: Previous graphic but with added 'layer lines' now at a 45-degree angle to forces 1 and 2]

The formula to find the exact angle to print the object at, based on the 
distance between the holes, is what I'm after.

Comment: I think the number of variables involved in such a concept prevents the creation of a formula. Your layer alignment is not limited to linear, as one can adjust infill density and patterns in a substantial manner. As an example, the parameter of "outside layers" can be so high as to make a formula impossible. The printing orientation shown complicates the results as well. I suppose one could specify an exact configuration of parameters and create an ersatz formula, but it would change with the smallest of adjustments.

Comment: Well, the infill pattern changes on two axes (X&Y), not the layer line axis (Z) looked at here. Primarily, these parts are failing from the layers peeling apart from each other. So if we assume 100% infill in designing a formula, it should be the same for all infill patterns, since all infill patterns have the same layer peeling risks in the Z direction at 100% infill… This is partly related to some calling this decade’s 3D printing slicers “2.5D printing”. The Z axis changes consistently throughout the print (e.g. 0.2mm layer height each print). Changing the angle of the Z lines is the point…

Comment: So perhaps the layers separate due to the previous layer having too much time to cool before the next layer is applied - that may be worth investigating.

Comment: Actually that didnt work but is online everywhere. What worked was lowering the steps per mm for the Z axis…. But regardless,  I’m trying to learn about this factor too

Comment: try this search - https://duckduckgo.com/?q=isotropy+in+3d+printed+parts

Comment: Think about how to let it deform so it does not break.  Layers aren't everything.  Also consider molding.  You can make a pretty cheap mold with foil and wood.  Pressure while molten is what you need in order to make plastic bond.